# Where are the 'preloaded' images for the composer

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add a North arrow to a map in the composer in QGIS 2.0 on a Mac.

Googling tells me to simply add one from the preloaded images.  When I click the add image icon I get a dialogue box asking for a directory to find the images.  All the tutorials seem to assume that clicking on the add image button will bring up a bunch of handy images.  I am fairly new to QGIS and have not got this far with 1.8.

I can't find any docs specific to 2.0 and the print composer manual has not been updated yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to expand the **Search directories** section

[image]